# is there a way to speed up recursively loading Yahoo finance data and compare it to selected data using pandas especially for 100,000 of stocks

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop, optimization, yahoo-finance

I am currently new to StackOverflow and I would need your expertise on the following matter.
I am currently trying to create a function, that load data and convert it to the data frame using Panda but the problem with Yahoo finance is that not all Ticker(symbol) for all the stock can load the data, so I need to process through 100,000 of stocks and discard the one that is not working and use the one that is working.
I want to find a way of optimising this function but at the moment, I couldn't process more than 1,000 stocks per hr using only my CPU. I tried changing the function and optimising the best as I could but this is the most I can do and also using GPU to process it(it was a fail attempt since using GPU on this is not possible.)

```
def findAllCorrWithSelectStock(selectStock,listOfStock,start,end,newList):
list_withCorr = []
working_List = []
chosenAsset = web.DataReader([selectStock],'yahoo',start,end)['Adj Close']
for stock in listOfStock:   
# Set DataFrame as the Stock Ticker

    try:

        temp = web.DataReader(stock,'yahoo',start,end)['Adj Close']      

        closing_df = pd.merge(temp, chosenAsset, left_index=True, right_index=True).rename(columns={'Adj Close': stock})
        x = closing_df.corr().iloc[0][selectStock]
        if math.isnan(x) :
            pass
        else:

            list_withCorr.append((stock,closing_df.corr().iloc[0][selectStock]))
            newList.append(stock)


    except:
        pass

srt = sorted(list_withCorr,key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)
return srt
```

the problem is repetitive for a loop that repeats loading and comparing data.
the function will generate a rank of best-correlated stock given the select stock.
any help would be appreciated and It there is any problem or concern I caused you guys, I am very sorry in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This only handles one stock's comparison with all the others, right?

You are retrieving all the stock prices from Yahoo, *once for every stock*. Caching and reusing the data will cut the runtime by a factor of 100,000.

If you search a bit, I am also somewhat confident you will also find some torrents or other repositories of historic stock data. The open data stackexchange probably has pointers, or the eponymous subreddit.

And to add some more unsolicited advise: you aren't going to get rich by finding patterns in stock prices. Thousands of people work on such models, have access to far more data, processing power, and PhDs. All the "signal" is already stripped from the prices by the time they get to you, leaving you with the noise.

Comment: Thank you for your commit, this is just the university project that I'm interested in and especially about Bitcoin, can you elaborate on the following comment 'Caching and reusing the data will cut the runtime by a factor of 100,000.' and yes you are correct, I only retrieving it once for every stock.

Comment: so you just mean, load all the stock at once for 100,000 then just compare it at once for 100,000 stock